# jQuery is not pulling data from a JSON and adding the data - What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, drop-down-menu

I have a JSON file set up with data that, when a user on my site selects a music genre from a dropdown menu, songs of that music genre (the songs are stored in the JSON file, along with the artist) will be displayed in a combo box on my site. Sadly, this is not going according to plan.

I know that this error is based around some mistake that I am making, but I don't know where exactly! My browser's console is saying, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" on the following statement:

```
var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
```

However, I don't know what that means or if it's actually a legitimate runtime error. Anyways, here is my code. I would really appreciate it if you awesome people could look over my code and see what you think may be causing my code to not act in the way that I want to it to act (detailed in the first paragraph) :)

## JSON

```
{
    "library":
    [
        // ROCK
        {
            "title": "Your Love",
            "artist": "The Outfield"
        },
        {
            "title": "Voodoo Child",
            "artist": "Jimi Hendrix"
        },
        {
            "title": "When I'm Gone",
            "artist": "Three Doors Down"
        },
        // ALTERNATIVE
        {
            "title": "Jumper",
            "artist": "Third Eye Blind"
        },
        {
            "title": "One Week",
            "artist": "Barenaked Ladies"
        },
        {
            "title": "The Middle",
            "artist": "Jimmy Eat World"
        }
    ]
}
```

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Declare our needed variables
    var dropDown = $("#music-genre");    // <select id="music-genre">...</select>
    var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
    var target = $('#song');    // <select multiple id="song">...</select>


    // If "Alternative" is chosen, choose the alternative songs
    // I didn't add a conditional statement for choosing "Rock" because it's the same
    if (selectedValue == "Alternative")
    {
        // "data/music.json" is the location of my JSON file
        $.getJSON("data/music.json", function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(key, val)
            {
                target.innerHTML += '<option value="' + val.title + '">' + val.title + 'by ' + val.artist + '</option>';
            }); // END $.each
        }); // END $.getJSON
    } // END if
}); // END ready()
```

## HTML

```
<!-- Drop Down -->
<select id="music-genre">
    <option id="rock" value="rock">Rock</option>
    <option id="alternative" value="alternative">Alternative</option>
</select>

<!-- Combo Box -->
<select multiple id="song">
    <!-- "Select one or more" is disabled because I don't want users selecting it -->
    <option value="select" disabled>Select one or more</option>
</select>
```

Comment: *"...or if it's actually a legitimate runtime error"* Of course it's legitimate.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I thought maybe it wasn't pertinent for the code to run through successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your the data you want from your returned JSON is in the `library` array, so you need to use `data.library`.

Also note that `target` will be a jQuery object which does not have a `innerHTML` property, so you need to use `append` instead:

```
$.each(data.library, function(key, val) {
    target.append('<option value="' + val.title + '">' + val.title + 'by ' + val.artist + '</option>');
})
```

Finally as others mentioned you can use the `val()` property on a `select` element to get the selected value:

```
var selectedValue = $("#music-genre").val();
```

Comment: I implemented the changes you suggested, which certainly rid me of the console error, but the combo box is still not filling up with anything besides what I put in the combo box within my HTML :(

Comment: No console errors are present. This boggles the mind!

Comment: Got it working! my `var target = $('#song');` needed double quotation marks, instead of single quotation marks. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it like this:

JSON:

```
{
"library": {
    "rock": [
        {
            "title": "Your Love",
            "artist": "The Outfield"
        },
        {
            "title": "Voodoo Child",
            "artist": "Jimi Hendrix"
        },
        {
            "title": "When I'm Gone",
            "artist": "Three Doors Down"
        }
    ],
    "alternative": [
        {
            "title": "Jumper",
            "artist": "Third Eye Blind"
        },
        {
            "title": "One Week",
            "artist": "Barenaked Ladies"
        },
        {
            "title": "The Middle",
            "artist": "Jimmy Eat World"
        }
    ]
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    // Declare our needed variables
    var dropDown = $("#music-genre");    // <select id="music-genre">...</select>
    // var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
    var target = $('#song');    // <select multiple id="song">...</select>

    dropDown.on("change", function(){
        var genre = $(this).val();
        var html = '';
        $.getJSON("test.json", function(data){
            $.each(data.library[genre], function(key, val){
                html += '<option value="' + val.title + '">' + val.title + 'by ' + val.artist + '</option>';    // Save whole html in a var
            }); // END $.each*/
            target.html(html);  // append it in target div
        }); // END $.getJSON
    });
}); // END ready()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var selectedValue = dropDown.find(':selected').val();
```

or:

```
var selectedValue = dropDown.val();
```

instead of:

```
var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
```

since `dropDown` is a jQuery object which required you to use jQuery method here.

---

Also note that `data` contains `library` array, so you need to access this array to get the value inside:

```
$.each(data.library, function(key, val) {
    target.innerHTML += '<option value="' + val.title + '">' + val.title + 'by ' + val.artist + '</option>';
});
```

Comment: I modified those lines of code you suggested, but apart from no more console error, nothing has changed on the web page when choosing different items in the dropdown menu.